# How to find discrete Z-transform of a list of complex numbers

Tags: integral-transforms

Can we find the discrete Z-transform of **a list of complex numbers** in Mathematica?

Similar to the function `Fourier` for the discrete Fourier transform, do we have a function for Z-transform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, to find the Z-transform, use the function `ZTransform[]`.  To compute the inverse Z-transform, of a function, `InverseZTransform[]`.

[image]

Works with complex numbers:

[image]

And explicit lists of complex numbers!

[image]

Comment: The right function to use is `ListZTransform[]`, as the OP mentioned "a list of complex numbers"; `ZTransform[]` is intended for functions.

Comment: Thanks, but for `ZTransform[expr,k,z]`, we need `expr` to be expressed in terms of `k`, I cannot use if for a series of complex numbers. I want something similar to `Fourier[list]`

Comment: @J.M.isslightlypensive, Great! This is it. Thank you

Comment: The Z-transform is linear so $\cal{Z} (a+ i b) = \cal{Z} (a) + i \cal{Z} (b)$.  Also, `ZTransform[]` takes complex input, for example `ZTransform[Exp[I k],k,z]` works as intended.  But you are right!  I did not pay enough attention to your request for working with complex numbers!

Comment: @J.M., Yes, I see, ... I guess it depends what we want to use the list for.  If we simply want the Z-transform of a list, then the result is a list!   If we want the list to imply a sequence, then `ListZTransform[]` is the way to go.  Thank you!